# after installing jupyter locally, I can't run jupyter notebook

Tags: python, linux, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

On linux redhat: 
I tried to install jupyter locally:

```
$ pip install jupyter --user
```

and it seems as everything was installed properly...

But - I cannot runt **jupyter notebook**, nor **~/.local/bin/jupyter notebook**
Why?

The installation...

> $ pip install jupyter --user 
>   Collecting jupyter   Using cached
>   jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Requirement already satisfied:
>   ipywidgets in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   (from jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: notebook in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   widgetsnbextension>=1.2.6 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.3.3;
>   sys_platform != "win32" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: pygments in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   qtconsole->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   jupyter-console->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: mistune!=0.6
>   in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   nbconvert->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   nbconvert->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: decorator in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   traitlets>=4.2.1->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   enum34; python_version == "2.7" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   traitlets>=4.2.1->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   six in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   traitlets>=4.2.1->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   setuptools>=18.5 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   simplegeneric>0.8 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   pickleshare in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   backports.ssl-match-hostname in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   backports-abc>=0.4 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: certifi
>   in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   singledispatch in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   ptyprocess in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   (from terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32"->notebook->jupyter)
>   Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   jinja2->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0 in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   nbformat->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13
>   in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   jupyter-client->notebook->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   wcwidth in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter) Requirement
>   already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   entrypoints->nbconvert->jupyter) Requirement already satisfied:
>   functools32; python_version == "2.7" in
>   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0->nbformat->notebook->jupyter) Installing
>   collected packages: jupyter Successfully installed jupyter-1.0.0

Comment: Does ~/. local/bin/jupyter exist? What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Set two variables first whose CMD commands are below:
`set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython`
Now run pyspark with command `pyspark`, which will open 8888(default) port with jupyter running initiated sparkContext.

Comment: @Dror...If your problem is solved, mark the answer correct to increase confidence of other people towards answer.