# Fixing installation: jupyter notebook

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to install jupyter like following the instructions:

```
sudo easy_install pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install jupyter
```

Everything worked out OK - when installing

```
  python -m pip install jupyter
```

this appeared:

```
ipython 5.6.0 requires backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7", which is not installed.
```

Also fixed, with

```
pip install --upgrade backports.shutil_get_terminal_size

Collecting backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
Using cached backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size
```

I simply ignored everything with matplotlib.

But then I tried to run jupyter typing into bash:

```
jupyter notebook
```

And what I got is:

```
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

I already tried

```
open -e ~/.bashrc
```

like suggested here:
[After installing with pip, -bash: Jupyter: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862390/after-installing-with-pip-bash-jupyter-command-not-found) 
but this appeared:

```
 The file /Users/ME/.bashrc does not exist.
```

Also tried [after installing jupyter locally, I can't run jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588398/after-installing-jupyter-locally-i-cant-run-jupyter-notebook)

```
~/.local/bin/jupyter

-bash: cd: /.local/bin/jupyter: No such file or directory
```

Has someone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Potential issues: (1) It is .bashrc I believe, not bashrc (there is a dot). (2)  I think it should be .local, not local (dot again) (3) ~/.local/bin/jupyter is not the same as /local/bin/jupyter. I do not know if these will solve your problem, so this is not an answer, but worth checking once.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding where the jupyter command has been installed to by running a find command from the root directory.

```
cd /
find . -name 'jupyter' -perm -111 -type f -print 2>/dev/null
```

The 2>/dev/null prevents error messages being displayed.

-perm -111 -type f prints out executable files only.

This should give you the path to your jupyter executable. To make life easier, you can put an alias to where the executable is into the .bashrc file in your home directory. It looks like this file does not exist for you, so you could create one using any text editor, such as gedit or vim. Instructions on how to create aliases and use a .bashrc file are easily found online.